# How to test serialize column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rspec-rails

I have in my model this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :my_column, Array
end
```

How do I test it?

Today I'm testing this:

```
it "column serialize Array" do
 subject.my_column.is_a?(Array).must_equal true
end
```

I'm using `gem "minitest-rails-shoulda"`

Is there another way to test this?

Tanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers).

```
class MyModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should serialize(:my_column)
end
```

Check out the [code comments](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/b58f0a1807a4346399aa3b9bb5b88923ab9aa2e5/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/serialize_matcher.rb), everything should be pretty straightforward.

If you are on Rails 5, watch out as there currently is [an issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/913).

Answer (score 0):

`serialize` stores an object in the db, so you want to test that you can reload after saving (the YAML transformation is successful). do something like this:

```
it "column serialize Array" do
  obj = MyModel.new 
  obj.my_column = [1,2,3]
  obj.save!
  obj.reload.my_column.should == [1,2,3]
end
```

Comment: I don't need to know that it saves, because the serialize already ensures  it to me. I just need to test it in my model that column has a serialize Array. I'm not saving anything in the database in my tests, only in specific cases.